# Node.js Getting Error when saving session in database, Sails.js using sails-mongo module?

Tags: node.js, session, sails.js, sails-mongo

i have gone through the sails doc  http://sailsjs.org/documentation/reference/configuration/sails-config-session 
db configuration is

```
  adapter: 'sails-mongo',
  host: 'localhost',
  port: 27017,
  db: 'sails',
  collection: 'sessions',
```

Getting error -->

> A hook (`session`) failed to load! error: Could not load Connect
>   session adapter :: sails-mongo installed "sails-mongo" by using npm
>   install sails-mongo

Answer (score 1):

Sails.js uses a different connector for sessions, that is why you are having this problem. All you need to do is install and configure the connect-mongo package to use the same mongodb configured for your data:

---

You need to run install connect-mongo using npm:

> npm install --save connect-mongo

Also, you nees to configure the session adapter in the config/session.js file. And it uses a different format:

```
// Note: user, pass and port are optional
url: 'mongodb://user:pass@host:port/database',
collection: 'sessions',
auto_reconnect: false,
ssl: false,
stringify: true
```

All this information is available on this page of the docs:
[Sails.js session Documentation](http://sailsjs.com/documentation/reference/configuration/sails-config-session)